# json path for response - API Restassured

Tags: api, response, rest-assured

Below is the response i get for post call.
How to get quoteId and fee amount value using Json from the below response.

```
{
    "data": {
        "quoteId": "Lid123",
        "loanTerm": "48.0",
        "lenderRate": "4.5",
        "customerRate": "4.499999999999904",
        "fees": [
            {
                "feeType": "EstablishmentFee",
                "feeAmount": "450"
            }
        ],
        "periodPaymentInclGSTAmount": "6416.5"
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey man, it's json, not xml. Correct the title and tag to attract others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jsonpath()` method to extract value from json.

```
Response res = ...
String quoteId = res.jsonPath().getString("data.quoteId");
String feeAmount = res.jsonPath().getString("data.fees[0].feeAmount");
System.out.println(quoteId);   //Lid123
System.out.println(feeAmount); //450
```

Answer (score 0):

String id = JsonPath.from(reponseBody).getString("data.quoteId");

String EstablishmentFee = JsonPath.from(reponseBody).getString("data.fees.feeAmount");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).